# How to Union By name for the dynamic drop of files into blob in Azure data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My File 1 has
a,b,c
1,2,3

File 2 has
e
23
I am doing the Wildcard path as "*.txt"

My Expected Result should be :
a,b,c,e
1,2,3,NULL 
NULL,NULL,NULL,23

But it came as :
a,b,c
1,2,3
23,NULL,NULL

I have Schema drift is ON. Even though Schema is not drifted.

**Scenario added :
I can get 100 files a day or 2 files a day which get dropped on a daily basis in the ADLS .
How to union by name dynamically in dataflow**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unioning files using wildcard character will union all files by the column position only. Instead, you can use union transformation to achieve your requirement. In Union settings, select **Union by** as **Name**.

I have reproduced this with sample datasets.

**Input Dataset- source1:**
[image]

**Input dataset- source2**

[image]

- Union transformation settings is given as in below image. Select Union by as Name.
  [image]

**Output of UNION transformation:**
Output data is as expected
[image]

Comment: Ha Hah. I Know its UnionByName ,but my case is no of files is unknown ,like its dynamic .One day there can be 100 files to fetch , there can be one file to fetch .So keeping static sources and unioning them is not am expecting. Thats why I have went to Wild card .Can you suggest any other way to get all the files dynamically and unionByName .

Comment: It is not possible to union by column name while using wild card.

Comment: Added /Edited scenario. Can you suggest how to actually achieve this.

Comment: Ask another question on this, so that community can answer your question.

Comment: I have editted the question. But O will add up another question too.

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve this requirement. You can use for loop and dataflow activity with union of two files in ADF to achieve your requirement. Share the new Question. I will post the detailed approach

Comment: Yeah.added another question. Please check that out